# Term for animals that live under water

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term for animals that live under water (not necessarily in an ocean)? Ideally this would include sharks, dolphins, crabs, seashells, salmons and pet fish. Here are some I can come up with, but none sound right:

- Aquatic Animals
- Ocean Creatures
- Ocean Animals
- Marine Lives
- Marine Animals
- Marine Creature

Comment: Wikipedia: An aquatic animal is an animal, either vertebrate or invertebrate, which lives in water for most or all of its life.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Aquatic animal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquatic_animal)** might fit best here. I just couldn't think of a better one.

Comment: Totally agreed, there can surely be no better term for "things that live under water" than _aquatic animal_. If you were restricting the scope of your question to the open ocean, as suggested by the title of the post, then _[pelagic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pelagic)_ would be appropriate.